# Sjplot non-numeric argument to binary operator bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I think there is a glitch in the sjplot package, but wanted to ask what people thought first. Here is my code that produces an error, which from my understanding should work just fine

```
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
efc <- to_factor(efc, c161sex, e42dep, c172code)
m <- lm(neg_c_7 ~ pos_v_4 + c12hour + e42dep + c172code, data = efc)

# create plot-object
p <- plot_model(m, type="pred")

# change theme
p + labs(x="")
```

I get this `Error in p + labs(x = "") : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Depending on the plot-type, plot_model() returns a ggplot-object or a list of such objects.

And indeed:

```
class(p)
#[1] "list"

length(p)
#[1] 4
```

You have four ggplot2 objects in a list. You'll need to change the labels for each of them (e.g., by iterating over the list).